# Can't access Artifactory using my ip address

Tags: localhost, artifactory

I'm running artifactory-oss-7.15.4 on http://localhost:8046 on my windows machine. The problem is that I cannot access it using my local IP address eg. http://10.10.XX.XX:8046 and I'm not sure why. I have gitlab running on a VM and am trying to use artifactory to store my Gitlab artifacts but cannot access artifactory due to this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @tomothy - Is this a docker install? Why don't you access via 8082? 8046 is configured only for localhost access.

Comment: @PrasannaRaghavendra Thanks I didn't realise I could access it on 8082. It's working now thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks - adding it as the answer for others to reach here. Please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 7.x, When Accessing Artifactory from outside the box, it needs to be accessed via 8082 - 8046 is configured only for localhost access.